matplotlib does not plot two figures on the same plot
(fully reproductible copy-and-paste example)
I have the following code on my Jupyter Notebook and my goal is to plot the three lines on the same plot. Moreover, only two lines are being plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
def plot_metric_from_history() -> None:

    metric_dict = {'accuracy': [('0', '98.82'),
                                ('1', '98.87'),
                                ('2', '98.9'),
                                ('3', '98.91'),
                                ('4', '98.98'),
                                ('5', '98.89'),
                                ('6', '98.99'),
                                ('7', '99.05'),
                                ('8', '99.0'),
                                ('9', '99.03')]}
    expected_maximum = "0.9924"
    
    # Convert values to float 
    metric_dict['accuracy'] = ([(int(round_num), float(accuracy_val)) for round_num, accuracy_val in
                                      metric_dict['accuracy']])
    
    rounds, values = zip(*metric_dict["accuracy"])
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.plot(rounds, values, label="FedAvg")
    
    # Set the apect ratio to 1.0
    xleft, xright = axis.get_xlim()
    ybottom, ytop = axis.get_ylim()
    axis.set_aspect(abs((xright - xleft) / (ybottom - ytop)) * 1.0)

    # Set expected graph for data
    plt.axhline(
        y=float(expected_maximum),
        color="r",
        linestyle="--",
        label=f"Paper's best result @{expected_maximum}",
    )
    
    # Set paper's results
    plt.axhline(
        y=0.99,
        color="silver",
        label="Paper's baseline @0.9900",
    )
    
    plt.ylim([0.97, 1])
    plt.title(f"Validation - MNIST")
    plt.xlabel("Rounds")
    plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
    plt.legend(loc="lower right")
    

    # Set the apect ratio to 1.0
    xleft, xright = axis.get_xlim()
    ybottom, ytop = axis.get_ylim()
    axis.set_aspect(abs((xright - xleft) / (ybottom - ytop)) * 1.0)

    plt.show()

plot_metric_from_history()


I know the third line is there because if I do a plot.show() right after plt.plot(rounds, values, label="FedAvg") I can see it. Is the image below.

The question then is:

How can I plot both images (i.e. the three lines) on the same plot?


There is no problem with your plot code. You are mixing scales, one is a percentage and the other is per unit. The axhlines are at around 0.9 but your data is of the order of 99.0. Fixing this, the plot looks ok.
#Convert values to float 
metric_dict['accuracy'] = (
    [(int(round_num), float(accuracy_val)/100.)
    for round_num, accuracy_val in metric_dict['accuracy']]
)


